# Sending metrics to Datadog through API - Limits

Tags: java, metrics, unix-timestamp, datadog

Looking at https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/metrics/#submit-metrics

I am able to send metrics to datadog but there is a caveat. In their model, there is a requirement that each value must be tied to a timestamp,but the timestamp should be in seconds and current. Current is defined as not more than 10 minutes in the future or more than 1 hour in the past.
[image]

I am trying to send metrics outside of that timeframe but unable to do so. Which other method can be used?? Thanks.

Comment: What is your use case?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Datadog folks might have a feature in beta that would allow modifying timestamps further in the past. If you have a Datadog contact, you can ask if they can enable that for you for specific metrics that you send.

If this isn't enough, I'm afraid that Datadog might not match your use case. It has very specific operational use cases for which it shines, but not usually when you want to analyze or ingest data with timestamps in the past.